# cPanel Error while creating email account. Error: No specific error was returned with the failed API Call

Tags: email, centos, cpanel, whm

**cPanel is giving the attached error while I am trying to create the email account.**

[image]

Comment: How is this a programming question please ?

Comment: This is not a programming question. This is related a cPanel issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found a solution while digging this issue. You must have the following folders in your home directory to create the email account.

> - public_html
> - public_ftp
> - mail
> - etc

etc folder which was missing in my home directory. I have added it and the issue is fixed!